# How can I get a GPUImageUIElement over a blur video without blurring the element itself

Tags: ios, gpuimage, movie

Here I have a video, I want to add a watermark in the end of the video. The requirement is to blur the last second, and put a GPUImageUIElement over the video.  Here is what I want:

[image]

But it turns out to be like this:

[image]

I only want to blur the movie, not the label.

And here's my process:

```
self.originMovie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithAsset:video];

self.regularFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];

self.blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
self.blendFilter.mix = 1.0;

self.combinationViewElement = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:self.combinationView];


self.regularFilter.frameProcessingCompletionBlock = ^(GPUImageOutput *output, CMTime time){
    [weakSelf updateCombinationWithTimestamp:time];
    [weakSelf.combinationViewElement update];

};




AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[video tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] firstObject];

GPUImageUIElement *watermarkElement = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:self.watermarkView];

self.watermarkBlurFilter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurPositionFilter alloc] init];
self.watermarkBlurFilter.blurSize = 0;

GPUImageFilter *filter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];
filter.frameProcessingCompletionBlock = ^(GPUImageOutput *output , CMTime time) {
    if (isnan(weakSelf.originMovie.progress)) {
        return;
    }

    CGFloat duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(weakSelf.originMovie.asset.duration);
    if ([weakSelf isWithinWatermarkDuration]) {
        // 从最后一秒开始，blurSize从0线性递增到3
        weakSelf.watermarkBlurFilter.blurSize = ((weakSelf.originMovie.progress * duration ) + (1 - duration)) * 3;

        weakSelf.watermarkView.hidden = NO;
    }

    [watermarkElement update];

    if (weakSelf.progressHandler) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            weakSelf.progressHandler(weakSelf.originMovie.progress);
        });

    }
};

GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *watermarkBlendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
watermarkBlendFilter.mix = 1.0;


self.movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:self.videoURL size:videoTrack.naturalSize];
self.movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;

self.originMovie.audioEncodingTarget = self.movieWriter;
[self.originMovie enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:self.movieWriter];


[self.originMovie addTarget:self.regularFilter];

[self.regularFilter addTarget:self.blendFilter];
[self.combinationViewElement addTarget:self.blendFilter];

[self.blendFilter addTarget:self.watermarkBlurFilter];

[self.watermarkBlurFilter addTarget:filter];

[filter addTarget:watermarkBlendFilter];
[watermarkElement addTarget:watermarkBlendFilter];

[watermarkBlendFilter addTarget:self.movieWriter];


[self.movieWriter startRecording];
[self.originMovie startProcessing];
```

The combinationViewElement is my other process, doesn't relative to this question. 
I don't know if I make a mistake, so anyone has any idea, please let me know, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're adding your blur filter after the blend where you emboss the UI element on your input movie. You need to move your blur filter so that it comes after `self.regularFilter`, but before that is fed into `self.blendFilter`.

Having the blur after the blend will just blur the entire blended image.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here. I don't use self.blendFilter to blend the watermark. It's the watermarkBlendFilter that do the trick. So I did put the watermarkBlendFilter after the blur filter, but it still blur all.